# .listFiles() returned file object returns false on .exists() - file contains special character(s)

Tags: java, file, special-characters, readfile

I've got a java application zipping a given directory. A file is omitted containing a special character (e.g. an umlaut - ä, ö, etc.). Debugging showed, that the file is omitted because it does not exist

```
if(file.exists()) {
  //zip it
} else {
  System.err.println("file " + file.getAbsolutePath() + " does not exist!");
}
```

The thing is - I retrieve the file object from

```
File[] files = directory.listFiles();
```

and then iterrate through them.

```
for(File file : files) {
  if(file.exists()) {
    //zip file
  } else {
    System.err.println("...");
  }
}
```

What I saw is, that `file.getAbsolutePath()` shows me the following path `/tmp/myspecialChar?File.txt` instead of `/tmp/myspecialCharÖFile.txt`.

Any ideas how to get hold of the File. Unfortunately all special characters will be translated into "?" so I cannot implement a mapping. Listing names returns also "?" instead of the correct special character.

Before I forget - the JVM version is 1.6.31.

Comment: which OS are you working with?

Comment: it is an ubuntu 10.04 linux

Comment: the file also got generated on that machine (in case you ask) - also the commandline shows the ? instead of an ä,ö,etc. but is able to work with it (referenced as ö or ? - so myöfile.txt is the same as my?file.txt)

Comment: I had almost the same problem some time ago, it had to do with now the filesystem where your file is was being mounted

Comment: @Gambrinus :  Its a bug....see [here](http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4733494). It suggests changing the default Locale to support unicode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the `file.encoding` system property of your JVM

```
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

Please, note this has to be done at the start-up as a `java` parameter. Doing it later with a `System.setProperty()` won't help as the value (that comes from the host OS) is already cached by then.

Comment: @Gambrinus can you try this answer? it looks plausible to me

Comment: tried it and it works ... didn't found the correct locale encoding - but it looks better :) myï¿œfile.txt

Comment: Glad to help mate. Thanks to @morgano for drawing your attention.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it works but try to use:

```
Ä, ä -> \u00c4, \u00e4
Ö, ö -> \u00d6, \u00f6
Ü, ü -> \u00dc, \u00fc
```

Replace the äöü with the \u at the right place for example:

```
for (File file : files) {
    String newfilename = file.getName().replace('Ü', \u00dc);
}
```

I am sorry if that dosen't work!

Comment: unfortunately this does not work - since I have no idea what the name is - that's why I list the directory contents. so a mapping is not feasable :( but good idea - maybe I find a way arround

Comment: Updated my answer is a little bit better but I think at this moment the äöü is already a ?. But maybe you find it usefull ^^